# Magento2 Incompatible argument type: Required type actual type error

Tags: magento2

I am running the setup:di:compile command. I have a module Ess/M2ePro. I face these errors during running this command.
[image]

All the errors belong to the same module. I am running Magento 2.3 and my PHP version is
PHP 7.2.34-4 on ubuntu18.04
My code for this file is here.

```
<?php

/*
 * @author     M2E Pro Developers Team
 * @copyright  M2E LTD
 * @license    Commercial use is forbidden
 */

namespace Ess\M2ePro\Model\Servicing\Task;

use Ess\M2ePro\Model\Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
use Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module;

/**
 * Class \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Servicing\Task\ChangedSources
 */
class ChangedSources extends \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Servicing\Task
{
    protected $componentRegistrar;
    protected $filesystemDriver;
    protected $fileReaderFactory;

    //########################################

    /**
     * DataProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config
     * @param \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Config\Manager\Cache $cacheConfig
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory $modelFactory
     * @param \Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory $helperFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param \Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Factory $activeRecordFactory
     * @param \Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Component\Parent\Factory $parentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar $componentRegistrar
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $filesystemDriver
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $fileReaderFactory
    */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $config,
        \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Config\Manager\Cache $cacheConfig,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory $modelFactory,
        \Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Factory $helperFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Factory $activeRecordFactory,
        \Ess\M2ePro\Model\ActiveRecord\Component\Parent\Factory $parentFactory,
        ComponentRegistrar $componentRegistrar,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $filesystemDriver,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\ReadFactory $fileReaderFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $config,
            $cacheConfig,
            $storeManager,
            $modelFactory,
            $helperFactory,
            $resource,
            $activeRecordFactory,
            $parentFactory
        );

        $this->componentRegistrar = $componentRegistrar;
        $this->filesystemDriver   = $filesystemDriver;
        $this->fileReaderFactory  = $fileReaderFactory;
    }

    //########################################

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPublicNick()
    {
        return 'changed_sources';
    }

    //########################################

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRequestData()
    {
        $responseData = [];

        try {
            $dispatcherObject = $this->modelFactory->getObject('M2ePro\Connector\Dispatcher');
            $connectorObj = $dispatcherObject->getVirtualConnector('files', 'get', 'info');
            $dispatcherObject->process($connectorObj);

            $responseData = $connectorObj->getResponseData();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->helperFactory->getObject('Module\Exception')->process($e);
        }

        if (count($responseData) <= 0) {
            return [];
        }

        $requestData = [];

        foreach ($responseData['files_info'] as $info) {
            if (!in_array($info['path'], $this->getImportantFiles())) {
                continue;
            }

            $basePath = $this->componentRegistrar->getPath(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, Module::IDENTIFIER);
            $fullPath = $basePath .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $info['path'];

            if (!$this->filesystemDriver->isExists($fullPath)) {
                $requestData[] = [
                    'path'    => $info['path'],
                    'hash'    => null,
                    'content' => null,
                ];
                continue;
            }

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\File\Read $fileReader */
            $fileReader = $this->fileReaderFactory->create($fullPath, $this->filesystemDriver);
            $fileContent = $fileReader->readAll();
            $fileContent = str_replace(["\r\n","\n\r",PHP_EOL], chr(10), $fileContent);
            $contentHash = call_user_func('md5', $fileContent);

            if ($contentHash != $info['hash']) {
                $requestData[] = [
                    'path'    => $info['path'],
                    'hash'    => $contentHash,
                    'content' => $fileContent,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $requestData;
    }

    //########################################

    public function processResponseData(array $data)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //########################################

    //todo Ruslan is going to change this list
    private function getImportantFiles()
    {
        return [
            'Model/Ebay/Actions/Processor.php',
            'Model/Amazon/Actions/Processor.php'
        ];
    }

    //########################################
}
```

I tried to add @params but it has no effect. What code changes do you suggest to solve this error.

Here is my di.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <!-- stockitem -->

    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_stockitem_magento_cataloginventory_model_stock_item"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\StockItem\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item" />
    </type>

    <!-- Bulk Update Products (Website) -->

    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_product_action_bulk_update"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Product\Action\BulkUpdate" />
    </type>

    <!-- order -->

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Config">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_order_magento_framework_app_config"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Order\Magento\Framework\App\Config" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_order_magento_quote_model_quote_item_toorderitem"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Order\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator\QuoteItemQtyList">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_stockitem_magento_cataloginventory_model_quote_item_quantityvalidator_quoteitemqtylist"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\StockItem\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator\QuoteItemQtyList" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollectorList">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_order_magento_quote_model_quote_totalscollectorlist"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Order\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollectorList" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\LoadHandler">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_order_magento_quote_model_quoteRepository_loadHandler"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\Order\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\LoadHandler" />
    </type>

    <!-- MSI -->

    <type name="Magento\Inventory\Model\Source\Command\SaveInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventory_model_source_command_save"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\Inventory\Model\Source\Command\Save" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventory_model_sourceitem_command_save"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem\Command\Save" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsDeleteInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventory_model_sourceitem_command_delete"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem\Command\Delete" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockSourceLinksSaveInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventory_model_stocksourcelink_command_save"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\Inventory\Model\StockSourceLink\Command\Save" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\StockSourceLinksDeleteInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventory_model_stocksourcelink_command_delete"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\Inventory\Model\StockSourceLink\Command\Delete" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventorySalesApi\Model\ReplaceSalesChannelsForStockInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventorysales_model_resourcemodel_replacesaleschannelsdataforstock"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\InventorySales\Model\ResourceModel\ReplaceSalesChannelsDataForStock" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\PlaceReservationsForSalesEventInterface">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventorysales_model_placereservationforsalesevent"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\InventorySales\Model\PlaceReservationsForSalesEvent" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\SetDataToLegacyStockItem">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventorycatalog_model_resourcemodel_setdatatolegacestockitem"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\InventoryCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\SetDataToLegacyStockItem" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryShipping\Observer\SourceDeductionProcessor">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventoryshipping_observer_sourcedeductionprocessor"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\InventoryShipping\Observer\SourceDeductionProcessor" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Processor">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_cataloginventory_model_indexer_stock_processor"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock\Processor" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\InventoryReservations\Model\ResourceModel\GetReservationsQuantityCache">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_msi_magento_inventoryreservations_model_resourcemodel_getreservationsquantitycache"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\MSI\Magento\InventoryReservations\Model\ResourceModel\GetReservationsQuantityCache" />
    </type>

    <!-- func_get_args() fix - see detailed explanation into the Plugin -->

    <type name="Ess\M2ePro\Helper\Module\Translation">
        <plugin name="m2epro_plugin_functionGetArgsFix_helper_module_translation"
                type="Ess\M2ePro\Plugin\FunctionGetArgsFix\Translation" />
    </type>

    <!-- fix for type error copied from vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/adminhtml/di.xml -->
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="variablePluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Variable\Model\Variable\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="widgetPluginConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Config</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="wysiwygConfigPostProcessor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="galleryConfigProvider" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Gallery\DefaultConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue on my custom module. I have fixed all compilation issue. You need to pass same parameters in parent construct method in given error file.

In your case, For example

```
app/code/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Servicing/Task/ChangedSources.php
```

In this check which block/model or controller is extends and check how many params are passed in construct.

You need to pass same parameters in parent construct.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I found this Ess/M2ePro module here https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension
I checked my install version which was 1.8.1, and latest version available was 1.18.1 so I deleted the old version files and added the files of new version. And it started working.